# How to get the emails sent on anther computer?

Tags: email, email-client

I use Foxmail to handle email in my company, now I'm back in school for a few days and I need to get a few emails that I sent in company. But I didn't see these options in Foxmail or Thunderbird, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution is to have an IMAP server for your company, and an IMAP server for your school and for both to be accessible through a remote Internet connection, either directly or through a VPN. You cannot create such a situation if youy only have control of the POP/IMAP client such as FoxMail or Thunderbird.

What many email clients do allow is that you can save a copy of sent emails locally (for example to your notebook/laptop hard disk) and save a copy of received emails there too ("offline working")

In the worst case you can use your email client to forward all received emails to a private account accessible from all locations. Use BCC to also send it a copy of all outgoing messages. This is quite a lot of effort though. Explore your email client's "offline" capabilities.